# Ionic Config Service (how to import)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking at the Ionic Config Service from here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/

I would like to use the Config functionality to set global configuration variables (in my case API keys). I'm struggling to get it to work however.

Whenever I call:

```
 config.set('ios', 'green', 'light');
```

It tells me that config is not defined. However I am unable to import Config as

```
 import { Config } from 'ionic-angular';
```

does not work. I thought it could be imported like the Platform Service but it does not seem like it. 
The documentation lacks further information.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `Config` dependency in the `constructor` of your component

```
import {Config } from 'ionic-angular';
```

`constructor(public config:Config){
 }`

Then, you can access it via

`this.config.get('favoriteColor');`